# Meteor.call is not reactive inside helpers

Tags: meteor

When I try to call methods inside helpers, reactivity doesn't work. here is my code :

**server side method code**

```
Meteor.methods({
getLastContact:function(){
        return contacts.findOne({},{sort: {contactID: -1},fields: {contactID:1}})
    }
})
```

**client side calling method**

```
Template.createVendor.helpers({   
  lastIDD: function () {
    Meteor.call('getLastContact',function(err,res){
        console.log(res.contactID);
    });   }});
```

if some new data is added, template helper losses reactivity and client does not get update. 
Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Method calls themselves are just remote procedure calls and have no notion of reactivity. Can you explain what you mean by "if some new data is added"? New data in the `contacts` collection or new data on the client which would cause the helper to be reevaluated?

Comment: new data to collection.

Comment: Can you just publish the contacts documents instead? Method calls are not what you want to use if reactivity is required.

Comment: I thought methods are secure way. Maybe you can help me with better solution. What I am trying to do is when page is loaded grab last record and add increment and record new row

Answer (score 1):

There is a package that makes meteor methods reactive. check out [meteor-reactive-method](https://github.com/stubailo/meteor-reactive-method).

It will do exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I saw that package. thank you for pointing out. But I need to understand why meteor is designed that way. Meteor documents are the worst, it is like another language needs interpretation

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling a method in client helpers you should use

```
return ReactiveMethod.call("method_name",Parameter1,Parameter2,..);
```

Include the package for ReactiveMethod call.